# Problem with quartz and SQL Server in Liferay EE

Tags: sql-server

I'm having a problem with quartz, it gives a `java.sql.SQLException` with this error message:

> ERROR [PortalJobStore:3799] ClusterManager: Error managing cluster: Failure obtaining db row lock: Line 1: FOR UPDATE clause allowed only for DECLARE CURSOR.

Apparently quartz in `Liferay Enterprise Edition` tries to use an SQL that isn't allowed by MSSQL.

What can be done to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tell quartz what SQL to use by adding this property `org.quartz.jobStore.selectWithLockSQL` in the file `portal-ext.properties` like this:

```
org.quartz.jobStore.selectWithLockSQL = SELECT * FROM {0}LOCKS UPDLOCK WHERE LOCK_NAME = ?
```

Comment: I actually joined serverfault only to upvote both your question _and_ answer. Thanks a lot!